# ASP.NET Identity editing logged in user's data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-identity

I have modified the Views/Manage/Index.cshtml to display the User's email as well. I've modified the IndexViewModel as well so it recognizes the "Email" string and then made another .cshtml page similar to the changing of phone number one which is there by default. The new page is called ChangeEmail.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeEmail", "Manage", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Add an email</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

From what I've seen, the changing of password happens through a task called "ChangePasswordAsync" inside UserManager.cs 
Is there a way to change the Email without making a new task?

EDIT: added more from the controller(index) :

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(ManageMessageId? message)
            {
                ViewBag.StatusMessage =
                    message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been changed."
                    : message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been set."
                    : message == ManageMessageId.SetTwoFactorSuccess ? "Your two-factor authentication provider has been set."
                    : message == ManageMessageId.Error ? "An error has occurred."
                    : message == ManageMessageId.AddPhoneSuccess ? "Your phone number was added."
                    : message == ManageMessageId.RemovePhoneSuccess ? "Your phone number was removed."
                    : message == ManageMessageId.EmailChangedSuccess ? "Your email has been changed"
                    : "";

                var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                var userEmail = User.Identity.Name;
                var user = UserManager.FindById(userId);



                var model = new IndexViewModel
                {
                    HasPassword = HasPassword(),
                    PhoneNumber = await UserManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(userId),
                    TwoFactor = await UserManager.GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(userId),
                    Logins = await UserManager.GetLoginsAsync(userId),
                    BrowserRemembered = await AuthenticationManager.TwoFactorBrowserRememberedAsync(userId),
                    Email = user.Email,
                    City = user.City,
                    Region = user.Region


                };
                user.Email = "topkek@ucn.dk";
                UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);

                return View(model);
            }

 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ChangeEmail(ChangeEmailViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }



            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = ManageMessageId.EmailChangedSuccess });
        }
```

Comment: `userManager.UpdateAsync(user);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the user's Email address from your `ChangeEmailViewModel` and then update the user's details using the `userManager.UpdateAsync(user)`

**EDIT**

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ChangeEmail(ChangeEmailViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }
             //Get the user's Id
            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId(); 

            //get the user (you can modify the variables to fit yours) 
           var user = UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

          //this is how to change the Email
          user.Result.Email= model.Email// **EDIT**;

         userManager.UpdateAync(user.Result);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = ManageMessageId.EmailChangedSuccess });
        }
```

Comment: can you please elaborate? I am not sure what goes where? thanks

Comment: I've added more details to the answer by using your post

Comment: When trying your method I am getting "userId does not exist in the current context". However I kind of got it to work by changing the Index() method (I've updated the original post above) and I can successfully change the email to "topkek@ucn.dk" however how can I do this inside ChangeEmail ? There is something I am missing

Comment: @crystyxn you were supposed to edit my example to fit your work. I just showed you that you need the userId, so get the UserId first like how you are doing it in your Index()

Comment: @crystyxn I've edited my answer to get the `UserId` before it passes it

Comment: I did add var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var user = UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId); and so far so good, then user.Email says there is no definition, however user.Result.Email seems to not give erros. Then the UserManager.UpdateAsync(user); underlines the user with red and says "cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Leepio.Models.ApplicationUser>' to 'Leepio.Models.ApplicationUser'

Comment: @crystyxn you should pass the Email you want to change through your `ChangeEmailViewModel` and I think you already doing that as I can see in your `View`

Comment: Then what can be the solution to this problem? I do not know what to look for

Comment: I have edited the part of my code where the `Email` is passed try that because I reckon that's what you are passing

Comment: Alright I finally got it to work! had to use user.Result.Email = model.Email; and then await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user.Result); !! this is why the error persisted, i was using only user ! thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @crystyxn Cheers! please edit my answer to include your changes so it helps anybody who comes across it. Thanks

Comment: Just did it! hope it helps someone in the future